# Convert Animation Nodes to Object and Keyframes

Tags: rendering, particles, animation-nodes, cache

I have This Node Tree in Animation Nodes:
[image]
As you can see it creates objects and edit their location.
but When I render, even If I normally bake all the Dynamics, the cache disappears and then it creates an image where there are particles, that weren't in the scene before rendering.
I think this problem is caused By animation Nodes. So is there a way to convert all nodes to actual objects, possibly keyframed so that the node tree isn't executed every time the frame change?

Comment: in the overview panel in the left sidebar is a Bake to Keyframes button. I think it should work in you case. (even without the Set Keyframes node)

Comment: I tried that but it only animates the objects created by then NodeTree. What I'm trying to achieve is to make the object created by the addon "real", so that if I delete the nodeTree, everything continues to exist like the nodeTree was still there.

Comment: Two options: 1. Once you baked the animation, you can disable Auto Execution completely to make sure that the node tree won't do anything anymore. 2. Checkout the advanced options of the Object Instancer. There is a button called "Unlink Instances from Node". When you press that, AN will forget about the existing instances (and possibly create new once). You can then remove the node tree and the objects will stay.

Comment: i used the 2nd option and it worked, thank you!