# Is it possible to use "Animation Nodes" when exporting it to a game engine?

Tags: animation, game-engine, animation-nodes

I want to export an animation to Godot game engine. Would that game engine specifically support the use of "Animation Nodes"

Comment: No, animation nodes are Blender exclusive data, unless you convert to static meshes it mostly can't be easily exported to game engines or otherwise. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As Duarte Correctly pointed out, animation nodes are Blender exclusive data. If you use a format that supports animations, such as Collada or Alembic, you should be able to export the animations as keyframe animations. However, this will only work for the basic location-rotation-scale animations, things like mesh deformations created with animation nodes will not be exported. A similar question has been asked here if you want a bit more info: [Blender page animation collada file in Scenekit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87209/blender-page-animation-collada-file-in-scenekit)

If you have any issues, you can also check out this question that the creator of the addon answered: [Convert Animation Nodes to Object and Keyframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76702/convert-animation-nodes-to-object-and-keyframes)